# How do you write the mathematical |x| in haskell?

Tags: haskell, math, module

How do you get the `(x - y) < 20` always positive?

I'd like to make a condition for:

```
getJOL :: [Int] -> String
getJOL [w,x,y,z] = if x - w < 20 && y - x < 20 && z - y < 20
                     then "Good calibration"
                     else "Bad calibration"
```

The difference between two values must be positive.

Comment: [`abs`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:abs)?

Comment: Don't return a `String`; if `getJOL` can only return two different values, then use a type that only *has* two values. You can use `Bool`, or a custom type with more descriptive values, like `data CalibrationStatus = GoodCalibration | BadCalibration`.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, `abs` is the function you want. That's the conventional name for |*x*| in most languages.

BTW you should probably not hard-code the case for exactly four list-elements. It's both unsafe (what if someone hands you a list with five elements?) and repetitive. Just *recurse* over the list, and abort when a pair with too large distance is found:

```
getJOL (w:x:ys)
  | abs (x - w) >= 20  = "Bad calibration"
getJOL (_:xs) = getJOL xs
getJOL [] = "Good calibration"
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use the absolute values `abs`. This will check, whether the absolute difference is lower than 20.

```
getJOL :: [Int] -> String
getJOL [w,x,y,z] = if abs(x - w) < 20 && abs(y - x) < 20 && abs(z - y) < 20
                     then "Good calibration"
                     else "Bad calibration"
```